# How to output a string list to console but have it not output duplicate string names

Tags: c#, list

My program currently reads in a chunk of text data from a file and stores it into a `String[]` Array. It then for each line splits it into a separate `String[]` Array, which from that I am breaking up each line and adding each string after a delimiter of `" "` to a `List` so I can compare every single property with one another.

Here is the data I am reading in.

`1508405807242 1508405807141 vader HELLO
1508405807340 1508405807350 luke HELLO
1508405807378 1508405807387 luke LOST vader
1508405807467 1508405807479 luke FOUND r2d2
1508405807468 1508405807480 luke LOST leia
1508405807512 1508405807400 vader LOST luke
1508405807560 1508405807504 vader HELLO`

I'm looking to output to console different actions from each character (luke, vader, r2d2 and leia) but only once. As soon as the most recent action has been output to the console I want it to move onto the next character.

Here is all of my code so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        // Get data from file and 
        String[] lines = new String[5];
        lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Ad\Desktop\data.txt");

        // 
        char delimiter = ' ';

        // Creating a new list from the DataItem class
        List<DataItem> dataList = new List<DataItem>();

        // Foreach loop reads in lines from String Array and populates the List with the relevant data for each property.
        foreach (String line in lines)
        {

            String[] data = new String[5];
            data = line.Split(delimiter);
            dataList.Add(new DataItem()
            {
                // Telling the application at which index each property starts
                MonitorTime = data[0],
                LocalTime = data[1],
                Actor = data[2],
                Notification = data[3],
                // If Actor2 doesn't have any data it populates the property with a null value
                Actor2 = data.Length > 4 ? data[4] : null
            });


        }

        // Orders the List so that the most recently received node is the one shown first
        List<DataItem> newList = dataList.OrderByDescending(x => x.LocalTime).ToList();

        // Loops through all lines and writes 
        foreach (var item in newList)
        {
            if (item.Notification.Equals("HELLO"))
            {

                Console.WriteLine(item.Actor + " " + "ALIVE" + " " + item.MonitorTime + " " + item.Actor + " " + item.Notification + " " + item.Actor2);
            }
            else if(item.Notification.Equals("LOST"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Actor2 + " " + "DEAD" + " " + item.MonitorTime + " " + item.Actor + " " + item.Notification + " " + item.Actor2);

            }
            else if (item.Notification.Equals("FOUND"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Actor2 + " " + "ALIVE" + " " + item.MonitorTime + " " + item.Actor + " " + item.Notification + " " + item.Actor2);
            }

        }



        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}


}
    // Class to hold different List items
    public class DataItem
    {
        public string MonitorTime { get; set; }
        public string LocalTime { get; set; }
        public string Actor { get; set; }
        public string Notification { get; set; }
        public string Actor2 { get; set; }
}
```

I would only like the first 4 entries to be displayed, instead of all 7, thanks.

EDIT:

The output should look like this:

`vader ALIVE 1508405807560 vader HELLO
luke ALIVE 1508405807468 luke LOST leia
r2d2 ALIVE 1508405807467 luke FOUND r2d2
leia DEAD 1508405807468 luke LOST leia`

If the 4th property in the string is "HELLO" the character is assumed to be alive.

If it is LOST then the 1st character is to be assumed as alive, but the 2nd character to be assumed dead.

If it is FOUND then both characters are to be assumed alive.

The output needs to be ordered by descending from the second property in the string (local timestamp) but should only show the first property (monitor timestamp)

I have already ordered the output correctly so all that needs doing is displaying the most recent action for each character, but I have no idea how.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: Could you show the correct output for the given input and why?

Comment: @npearson I have updated my post, hopefully you can make sense of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly you want to display the line only if there is a character that wasn't output yet.

For such cases you can use a `HashSet<string>`. This collection maintains a set (in mathematical terms) of items and may contain each unique item only once. It also has very efficient lookup.

```
HashSet<string> encounteredActors = new HashSet<string>();

//when an actor has been output
encounteredActors.Add( actorName );

//when you want to check if actor not yet encountered
if ( !encounteredActors.Contains( actorName ) )
{
   ...
}
```

So in your case, you would have to check like this:

```
HashSet<string> encounteredActors = new HashSet<string>();    
// Loops through all lines and writes 
foreach (var item in newList)
{
    if (item.Notification.Equals("HELLO"))
    {
        if ( !encounteredActors.Contains( item.Actor ) )
        {
           encounteredActors.Add( item.Actor );
           Console.WriteLine(item.Actor + " " + "ALIVE" + " " + item.MonitorTime + " " + item.Actor + " " + item.Notification + " " + item.Actor2);
        }
    }
    else if(item.Notification.Equals("LOST"))
    {
        if ( !encounteredActors.Contains( item.Actor2 ) )
        {
           encounteredActors.Add( item.Actor2 );
           Console.WriteLine(item.Actor2 + " " + "DEAD" + " " + item.MonitorTime + " " + item.Actor + " " + item.Notification + " " + item.Actor2);
        }
    }
    else if (item.Notification.Equals("FOUND"))
    {
        if ( !encounteredActors.Contains( item.Actor2 ) )
        {
           encounteredActors.Add( item.Actor2 );
           Console.WriteLine(item.Actor2 + " " + "ALIVE" + " " + item.MonitorTime + " " + item.Actor + " " + item.Notification + " " + item.Actor2);
        }
    }
}
```